# Add virtual folder to Apache like it was on htdocs folder

Tags: apache-2.2, alias, virtualhost

I would like to be able to go to `127.0.0.1/multimedia/any_file.ext` and see it like any other folder in htdocs. Here's what I'm trying in the configuration:

```
Alias "multimedia" "F://public_vids/"
<Directory "F://public_vids/">
  Options +Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've read the docs on the Apache website but not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to specify a path relative to the web root; that is:

```
Alias /multimedia F://public_vids
```

I've heard quotes can mess up some of the Apache config settings, so I would try removing them from the Alias directive, just in case.  If all else fails, try posting the relevant lines from your Apache access and error logs.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try this, thanks for your help guys